# Complex Monge Ampere measure with finite mass

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I was reading [this](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/46601/222_2005_Article_BF01418826.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) paper by Bedford-Taylor. It was proven in Theorem 2.4 that the Monge Ampere measure $(dd^c u)^n$ has a finite mass on any polydisc when $u$ is PSH and continuous up to the boundary of the Polydisc. My question is, if $\Omega$ be a $C^1$ smooth bounded domain and $u\in PSH(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ does $(dd^c u)^n$ has a finite mass on $\Omega$?